# which language most suitable for writing distributed opencl?

Tags: programming-languages, opencl, distributed-computing, grid-computing

I'm new to OpenCL in order to need help on choosing a language for writing a OpenCL program, There are many language(like c/c++ , python , java) available for that. I want to develop a application on distributed OpenCL using VirtualCL.

Comment: Use C or C++. Don't expect an OpenCL program to be easily portable: you'll need to tune it for some particular hardware!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will suggest you to use C++ for OpenCL program.

But literly speaking, the reason to use C++ rather than other languages is performance.
It is very fast at runtime than other languages.This allows writing very efficient code that still has high abstraction level.

The best way to phrase it is :

Less code, no run-time overhead, more safety.

Comment: Thank you .. one more question , which platform is easy to use (like windows or linux)?

Comment: linux is best platform for c++.

Comment: Another good reason to use C++ is that the C++ wrapper is much easier to use than the plain C version, with automatic cleaning of OpenCL classes. And it support error handling trough exceptions (if needed).